# Is there a data structure to grab values by x or y?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList with a lot of points (so x,y).
I sorted the points on XY.

Is there a datatype/algorithm to get all y points a certain x fast? (or the other way around, all x on a certain y).

At the moment I have something like this, which works ok but I have the feeling it's to complex for what I need.

```
int lastXPos;
int lastIndex;

int[] workArray = new int[4096];
int workArrayIndex;


// returns all the y values where x matches
public int[] grab(int xPos) {

    workArrayIndex = 0;

    int startIndex = 0;

    // this can increase speed a lot
    if (lastXPos+1 == xPos) {
        startIndex = lastIndex+1;
    }

    PVector v;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < vecs.size(); i++) {
        v = vecs.get(i);
        if (v.x > xPos) {
            lastIndex = i-1;
            break;
        }

        if (v.x == xPos) {
            workArray[workArrayIndex++] = (int) v.y;
        }

    }

    lastXPos = xPos;

    int[] result = new int[workArrayIndex];

    for (int i = 0; i < workArrayIndex; i++) {
        result[i] = workArray[i];
    }

    return  result;

}
```

Edit:

One more thing, it has to process a new list 60 times a second, so creating the data object also has to be fast.

Then as a bonus question, we have rows and columns, is there a way to describe both of those? (direction for example).

Comment: I take it by "fast" you mean "with a minimum of code" (as opposed to "using the smallest number of CPU cycles")?

Comment: Probably a `Map` where the key is `x`, and the value is an `ArrayList` of all the `y` values associated with that `x`.  A `HashMap` would be fastest, but if you still want to retrieve the points sorted by `x` then a `TreeMap` would be fastest at doing the sorted retrieval.

Comment: Additionally you can just use a List and call toArray instead of having two arrays and copying it by yourself.

Comment: @NPE smalles CPU cycles

Comment: Sounds like a job for a MultiMap (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) where key is X and the values are Y (@ajb: normal map would only allow one Y per X)

Comment: @verbose-mode You can map each `X` to a _list_ of `Y`, as I said in my comment.  That's how you can allow more than one Y per X without using a third-party library.